# How to capture the http response as a Json Object in Java

Tags: java, json, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to send a HTTP request using CloseableHttpClient and then capture the body of the response in a JSON object so I can access the key values like this: responseJson.name etc

I can capture the response body as a string ok using the code below but how can I capture it as a JSON object?

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();

    builder.setScheme("https").setHost("login.xxxxxx").setPath("/x/oauth2/token");
```

> ```
>     URI uri = builder.build();
>     HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
>     HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
>             .addPart("grant_type", grantType)
>             .build();
>     request.setEntity(entity);
>     HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
>     assertEquals(200, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
>
>     //This captures and prints the response as a string
>     HttpEntity responseBodyentity = response.getEntity();
>     String responseBodyString = EntityUtils.toString(responseBodyentity);
>     System.out.println(responseBodyString);
> ```

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Answer (score 6):

you can type cast your response string to JSON Object.

**String to JSON** using `Jackson` with `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`:

Assuming your json-string represents as this:  jsonString = "{"name":"sample"}"

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(responseBodyString);
String phoneType = node.get("name").asText();
```

Using [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseBodyString);
String name = jsonObj.get("name");
```

Comment: Great thanks Sree. I used JSONObject from your 2nd example. I had to add this to my POM: <dependency> <groupId>org.json</groupId> <artifactId>json</artifactId> <version>20180813</version> </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the string into `JSONObject` then get the value for `name`

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseBodyString);
System.out.println(obj.get("name"));
```

Comment: Thanks Deadpool. I have tried this but it says cannot resolve symbol 'JSONObject'.  
                                                                                                                                      
I have a 'JsonObject' available from com.google.json but nothing is recognised for JSONObject. Do I have to install a JAR or add something to my POM to access this?

Comment: Ah found it now, I added this to my POM:                                                                                        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is since you already have your JSON as a string, write a method which makes use of the google 'Splitter' object and define the characters on which you want to split into K-V pairs.

For example I did the same for K-V pairs as a string coming from a Spring Boot app and split based on the special ',' characters:

```
private Map<String, String> splitToMap(String in) {

    return Splitter.on(", ").withKeyValueSeparator("=").split(in);
}
```

replace with for example ": " and this should pick up your JSON string as K-V pairs.

Splitter Mvn dependency below:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

hope this helps you make a start.